# rsync / mv how to skip empty files

Tags: shell-script, rsync, mv

I have a requirement to copy files from source1 directory to destination1 directory and move from source1 directory to destination2 directory. It is working fine. But script is copying even empty files also. `rsync` / `mv` should not pick empty files. How can I do that? Currently I am using the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '------Files Copy------'
rsync -av /public/src1/ /public/dst1

echo '-------Files Move--------'
mv /public/src1/* /public/dst2
```

Comment: "`mv` should not pick empty files". Do you want empty files to remain in the source hierarchy? Or to disappear *as if* they were moved, but not to appear in the newly created hierarchy at the destination?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep empty files in the source directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `rsync` option `--min-size=1` to skip files smaller than 1 byte i.e. empty files:

```
rsync -av --min-size=1 /public/src1/ /public/dst1
```

From the manpage:

```
--min-size=SIZE         don't transfer any file smaller than SIZE
```

Comment: The `rsync` command could presumably be used as a drop-in replacement for `mv` too, if you add `--remove-source-files` (testing needed).

Comment: This (`--min-size=1`) is extremely important for rsync mirror backups. I just lost some very important files and my double backup didn't help, exactly because those original files (due to a bug) instead of having been wiped out, were zeroed, i,.e, became empty. Although my mirror rsync backup didn't have the flag `--delete`, I lost all these files because the blank files eventually replaced the good files at the backup storage.